# How to programmatically select QT QPA plugin

Tags: qt, qt5

I'm trying to make QT render to an image in a headless environment. I did it by passing a command line argument `--platform offscreen`. I prefer to do it programmatically but couldn't find any documentation. Does anyone know some way to do it?

Comment: Why QPA plugin? The answer from the text and not from the title depends on whether or not you do widgets or QML. If QML that is `--platform webgl` with `--opnegl es2` for Qt configure. http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/07/07/qt-webgl-streaming-merged/ But there problems with mouse and keyboard controls then and we need `--platform webapp` to launch and it is still in works.

Comment: http://blog.qt.io/blog/2018/05/22/qt-for-webassembly/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm actually doing widgets. I'll take a look at QML as well.